# How to filter random line with particular combination in text file using batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to filter a particular combination from the random lines in text file using my batch program.

This is to filter only email and password from a text file named file.txt in the combination of email:pass. unfortunately, other lines in the same text file also in same format someword:blank (example shown below)

The code i used,

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('type file.txt^|find ":"') do >>output.txt echo %%a
```

`file.txt` contains,

```
Username:
Password:
random1@gmail.com:password111
Subscription:
Recurring
Status:
Country:
Username:
Password:
random2@gmail.com:password222
Subscription:
Recurring
random3@gmail.com:password333
Status:
```

Expected output in `output.txt` is,

```
random1@gmail.com:password111
random2@gmail.com:password222
random3@gmail.com:password333
```

But, the actual output i got in `output.txt` is,

```
Username:
Password:
random1@gmail.com:password111
Subscription:
Recurring
Status:
Country:
Username:
Password:
random2@gmail.com:password222
Subscription:
Recurring
random3@gmail.com:password333
Status:
```

Am getting same output of the input file.

Comment: have you considered to filter by `@` instead of `:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't even need a `for` loop to do that. Just filter for `@`:

```
find "@" file.txt > output.txt
```